# How to sort data on partial column?

Tags: sort

I have data in a text file which I am trying to sort. I want to sort the data on the number at  position 2 of the 1st column to the end on the first column.

For example:

```
Record Age Price 
A7859   15    10
B785    18    10
C696548 11    10
X7675    35    10
Y679     45    10
Z65      89    10
```

Comment: Provide a sample file with expected output, as well as your research to solve the problem. The natural candidate is `sort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to sort on the numbers in the first column, numerically, in ascending order:

```
$ sort -k 1.2,1n file
Record Age Price
Z65      89    10
Y679     45    10
B785    18    10
X7675    35    10
A7859   15    10
C696548 11    10
```

The `-k 1.2,1n` option to sort means "sort using the data from the first column's second character, numerically".  This does a sorting of the numerical values in the first column in ascending order. Use `-k 1.2,1nr` to sort in reverse order.

The `,1` in that option's argument stops `sort` from using the rest of the line as the sorting key.

To clean up the alignment of the columns a bit, pass the result through `column -t`:

```
$ sort -k 1.2,1n file | column -t
Record   Age  Price
Z65      89   10
Y679     45   10
B785     18   10
X7675    35   10
A7859    15   10
C696548  11   10
```